# Error: Double :sponsor received unexpected message :users_with_unspent_rewards with (no args)

Tags: rspec

I have the following RSpec test:

```
describe "#users_with_unspent_rewards" do
    subject(:sponsor) { double(:sponsor) }
    let!(:reward) { double(sponsor: sponsor, cost: 300) }
    let!(:user) { double }

    before do
      allow(subject).to receive(:rewards).and_return([reward])
      allow(subject).to receive_message_chain(:users, :active).and_return([user])
      allow(subject).to receive(:any_rewards_user_can_buy?).with(user).and_return(true)
    end

    its(:users_with_unspent_rewards) { is_expected.to eq([user]) }
  end
```

My intent is that the method `users_with_unspent_rewards` should return any users whose unspent rewards' costs are greater than the sponsor's rewards' costs.

The error that I'm getting is this:

```
1) Sponsor#users_with_unspent_boost_rewards users_with_unspent_boost_rewards 
     Failure/Error: its(:users_with_unspent_rewards) { is_expected.to eq([user]) }
       Double :sponsor received unexpected message :users_with_unspent_rewards with (no args)
     # ./spec/models/sponsor_spec.rb:237:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

(Line 237 is the "its" line at the end of the method.

What I'm expecting to see is that the method 'users_with_unspent_rewards" should be flagged as not being defined in the Sponsor model.

The private method any_rewards_user_can_buy? is defined as follows:

```
def any_rewards_user_can_buy?(user)
  rewards.any? { |r| r.cost < user.boost_balance }
end
```

My proposed method is:

```
def users_with_unspent_rewards
  @users ||= users.active.select { |u| any_rewards_user_can_buy?(u) }
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem is in the first line of the spec:

```
subject(:sponsor) { double(:sponsor) }
```

I was stubbing the model under test.  Once I eliminated that line and removed the sponsor info from the reward defining line, the test passed.

Lesson learned:  don't stub either the model or the method under test - just the internals of the method.